# Unusual CODE 103 reason when attempting to access a morgan stanley account

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I'm getting this code and reason when attempting to connect to a morgan stanley account.

Code:103 The acquisitionrequest is missing a needed login credential value.

From what I understand a code 103 is invalid credentials.  At the same time, this is not the usual error response and i'm pretty sure the login/password given is correct.  Am I missing something on my discover request?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please enable logging in your app, and share the request/response XML(please share it in a support ticket)

Support link - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/9_other_resources/0030_support/0010_submit_support_incidents

Logging Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/devkits/0275_java_cad_devkit_1.0/0035_logging

It could be some service issue.

Thanks